# How to fill camp in a jsp form before updating

Tags: java, sql, forms, jsp, submit

I am trying to show the data of the user that I intend to update.

In my structure I enter a dni that is extracted when consulting a list, to then show the user's data in particular in another form. When this form is sent, the data will be permanently updated.

The problem I have is that I do not know how to show the user's data that I have previously searched for.
P.E: I am looking for a user called Jhon Doe with DNI 11111111E, in the second form I will have a new form with name and surname Jhon Doe, now I write in those fields of the form Mike Doe and press submmit.

The problem: I don, t know how to show the old name in my form (i don, t know hot to show Jhon Doe).

Here is my code, now i am stuck in that part, the update itseld is ok, but the name is not showed)

I have add my jsp web page to see how they works, but anyway my problem is about the way i manage to show the date from the user who will be updated.

My first jsp page here(V2formModificarUsuario1.jsp)

```
 <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario" />
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";
List<Usuario> usuarios = null;
DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();

try {
    //usuarios = dao.selectUsuario("si","nombre");
    usuarios = dao.selectAllUsuarios();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.toString();
}
%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>V2formListarUsuariosAltaNombre</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>   
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - LISTADOS USUARIOS</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Menu inicial</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="V2HojaUsuarios.jsp">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form id="formulario" action="V2formModificarUsuario2(en obras).jsp" method="POST">
                <label for="DNI">Intruduzca DNI del usuario</label><br> 
                DNI: <input type="text" name="DNI" required="">
                <input type="submit" value="buscar"> 
            </form>  
            <form>
                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="status_initial" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else { %>

                <br/><br/>

                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>DNI</th>
                        <th>nombre</th>
                        <th>apellidos</th>
                        <th>de alta</th>

                    </tr>
                    <%for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {%>
                    <tr>

                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getDNI()%></td>
                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getNombre()%></td>
                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getApellidos()%></td>
                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getDeAlta()%></td>

                    </tr>                            
                    <%}%>
                </table>
                <%}%>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My second jsp page here(V2formModificarUsuario2.jsp)

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario"></jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";


// String nameToChange = "";
String surnameToChange = "";

try {
    if ((usuario.getDNI() != null) && (!usuario.getDNI().isEmpty())) {
        DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();   

       // nameToChange=dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getNombre(); comentado por ahora
        surnameToChange=dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getApellidos(); 
        Usuario usuarios = dao.selectByDNI(usuario.getDNI());

        if (usuarios != null) {
            if ((usuario.getNombre() != null) && (!usuario.getNombre().isEmpty())
                    && (usuario.getApellidos() != null) && (!usuario.getApellidos().isEmpty())) {

                dao.update(usuario.getDNI(), usuario.getNombre(), usuario.getApellidos());
                message = "User correctly updated.";
            } else {
                if (request.getParameter("updating") == "1") {
                    message = "Los campos name, surname and deAlta are required .";
                }
            }
        } else {
            message = "user do not exists.";
        }
    } else {
        message = "DNI must not be null.";
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.getMessage();
}
%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSPformModificarUsuario2(en obras)</title>
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - USUARIO</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="V2formModificarUsuario2(en obras).jsp">
                <input name="updating" type="hidden" value="1"/>

                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="message" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else { %>

                <br/><br/>

                DNI:
                <input name="DNI" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="DNI" name="usuario"/>" readonly=""/>

                <br/><br/>
                nombre:
                <input name="nombre" type="text" style="width:200px" placeholder="<%=apellidoActualizar%>" value="<jsp:getProperty property="nombre" name="usuario"/>"/>

                <br/><br/>
                apellidos:
                <input name="apellidos" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="apellidos" name="usuario"/>"/>

                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Actualizar"/>

                <%}%>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And finally, My DAO here.

```
public Usuario update(String DNI, String nombre, String apellidos) throws Exception {
    if ((DNI == null) || (DNI.isEmpty())) {
        throw new Exception("DNI must not be null");
    }
    if ((nombre == null) || (nombre.isEmpty())) {
        throw new Exception("name must not be null");
    }
    if ((apellidos == null) || (apellidos.isEmpty())) {
        throw new Exception("surname must not be null");
    }

    Usuario usuario = selectByDNI(DNI);
    if (usuario == null) {
        throw new Exception("user do not exist");
    }
    try (Connection connection = DBConnection.get()) {
        if (connection == null) {
            throw new Exception("Connection is null");
        }

        String query = "UPDATE usuario SET nombre=?, apellidos=? WHERE DNI=?";

        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, nombre);
        statement.setString(2, apellidos);
        statement.setString(3, DNI);
        statement.execute();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        DBConnection.close();
    }
    usuario = selectByDNI(DNI);
    return usuario;
}

public Usuario selectByDNI(String DNI) throws Exception {
    if ((DNI == null) || (DNI.isEmpty())) {
        return null;
    }
    Usuario usuario = null;
    try (Connection connection = DBConnection.get()) {
        if (connection == null) {
            throw new Exception("Connection is null");
        }
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE DNI = '" + DNI + "'");

        if (rs.next()) {
            usuario = new Usuario(rs.getString("DNI"), rs.getString("nombre"),
                    rs.getString("apellidos"), rs.getString("deAlta"));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        DBConnection.close();
    }
    return usuario;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved, the response was qualified as repeated, but i am not agree, my solution is different:

I have created 3 forms, the first one search the DNI, the second one create an user object and fill the camps in a form(with a placeholder and a value for each one), and the last one is where i have made the updating for the user.

The code here.

### the second form in a jsp page

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario"></jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";
String nombreActualizar = "";
String apellidoActualizar = "";

try {
    if ((usuario.getDNI() != null) && (!usuario.getDNI().isEmpty())) {
        DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();
        nombreActualizar = dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getNombre();
        apellidoActualizar = dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getApellidos();
    } else {
        message = "El DNI  de actualización no puede ser nulo.";
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.getMessage();
}
%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSPformModificarUsuario2(en obras)</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - USUARIO</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Menu inicial</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="V2formModificarUsuario1(en obras).jsp">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="V2formModificarUsuario3(en obras).jsp">
                <input name="updating" type="hidden" value="1"/>

                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="message" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else {%>

                <br/><br/>

                DNI:
                <input name="DNI" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="DNI" name="usuario"/>" readonly=""/>

                <br/><br/>
                nombre:
                <!-- <input name="nombre" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<<!--jsp:getProperty property="nombre" name="usuario"/>"/>-->
                <input name="nombre" type="text" style="width:400px" placeholder="<%=nombreActualizar%>" value="<%=nombreActualizar%>"/>
                <br/><br/>
                apellidos:
                <!--<input name="apellidos" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<<!--jsp:getProperty property="apellidos" name="usuario"/>"/>-->
                <input name="apellidos" type="text" style="width:400px" placeholder="<%=apellidoActualizar%>" value="<%=apellidoActualizar%>"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Actualizar"/>

                <%}%>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### The third form in a new one jsp page

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario"></jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";
DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();
String DNIActualizado="";
String nombreActualizado ="";
String apellidoActualizado = "";

if (
        ((request.getParameter("DNI") == null) || (request.getParameter("DNI").isEmpty()))
     || ((request.getParameter("nombre") == null) || (request.getParameter("nombre").isEmpty()))
     || ((request.getParameter("apellidos") == null) ||(request.getParameter("apellidos").isEmpty()))
        ) {
    message = "Ningún campo del formulario debe estar vacio.";
}else{

DNIActualizado=request.getParameter("DNI");
nombreActualizado=request.getParameter("nombre");
apellidoActualizado=request.getParameter("apellidos");

usuario=dao.update(DNIActualizado, nombreActualizado, apellidoActualizado);
message = "usuario con DNI "+request.getParameter("DNI")+" actualizado";
```

}

%>

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSPformModificarUsuario3(en obras)</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - USUARIO</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Menu inicial</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="V2formModificarUsuario2(en obras)">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="V2formModificarUsuario3(en obras).jsp">
                <input name="updating" type="hidden" value="1"/>

                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="message" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else {%>

                <br/><br/>

                DNI:
                <input name="DNI" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="DNI" name="usuario"/>" readonly=""/>



                <%}%>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```